# Custom property type on array of objects

Tags: typescript, types

I have an array of objects, that all have the same shape:

```js
type Option = {
    label: string
    value: string | number | null
}

type ElementObject = {
    id: string
    options: Option[]
}

type ElementArray = ElementObject[]

const array: ElementArray = [
    {
        id: 'cars',
        options: [
            {
                label: 'One',
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                label: 'Two',
                value: 2,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'year',
        options: [
            {
                label: '70',
                value: '1970',
            },
            {
                label: 'Unknown',
                value: null,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

However as we can see, the value property type is unique to it's array - `options` on the `cars` object should have values of only `number`, while the same array on the `year` object can have `string` or `null`.

Is it possible to have more type safety than in the code where the value type is a union of all possible types?

I've tried to assert a more specific `Option` type directly inline/in place of the array definition, but TS doesn't enforce it - e.g. it doesn't complain if the values are of other type:

```js
const array: ElementArray = [
    {
        id: 'cars',
        options: [
            {
                label: 'One',
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                label: 'Two',
                value: 2,
            }
        ] as {
    label: string
    value: number
}[]
    },
    {
        id: 'year',
        options: [
            {
                label: '70',
                value: '1970',
            },
            {
                label: 'Unknown',
                value: null,
            }
        ] as {
    label: string
    value: null | string
}[]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```js
type Options<T> = {
  label: string;
  value: T;
};

type ElementObject<T> = {
  id: string;
  options: Options<T>[];
};

const anObject = [
  {
    id: 'year',
    options: [{ label: 'hello', value: '123' }],
  } as ElementObject<string | null>,
  {
    id: 'cars',
    options: [{ label: 'hi', value: 123 }],
  } as ElementObject<number>,
];
```

I think I can make this less declarative, like not needing the `as ElementObject<types>` every time but automatically using what you enters in `id`

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to assert the values: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFQHxQLxQG8AoKUqAGwEMAjCcgLigGdgAnBFAcxLIDdLyAVwiMMRAL5EioSFACi5CAFsIKYDGoArCAGNgmHPmKkEAE0Yt2XANw8k8ZCiaM4iVAYDaAXVvjbUgHoAqBloBWVVYABBVlZKEDx5RRU1DW09bykdVBYoSlj4xI8eUmMycrNGAHIdfKYqgBoS8qh7NydGYpbuwmaelqpaBigqmBQIRr7+vgFhRgBGJumycSXl3vWBmjpqjAB3JEnN8v4hERGAJiP1yX6vZvE8piSI1K1dfRRBJVpWLDXSlMTOYRiAIPlrt02o5nFAuusyscKNthlUAOwABkhx1Ocyg8wAnJiAdNVkCWojjoMdiMAKooADWKCQexQ2M2uPOX3I5BJ-VuPXu5UelGe4RS6neejQXx+ED+TXuQA

Comment: I didn't know about this tool, very useful. It does throw an error on my side, if you set the Module as `CommonJS` in the TS Config. I'm not sure about the differences though.